# Get Error when trying to request SSL certificate for a sub-domain in Virtual Min

Tags: linux, ssl, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, virtualmin

Get following error:

```
Web-based validation failed :
 Domain: qa.abcd.in
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://qa.abcd.in/.well-known/acme-challenge/qZopOPsOP6owwosX0W4t7qtDm7UTkOkBz6Ur2VsUi60
   [serverip]: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML
   2.0//EN\">\n<html><head>\n<title>404 Not
   Found</title>\n</head><body>\n<h1>Not Found</h1>\n<p"

DNS-based validation failed :
   Domain: qa.abcd.in
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: No TXT record found at
   _acme-challenge.qa.abcd.in
```

Have configured TXT record in Route 53 with value `_acme-challenge.qa.abcd.in`

Anyone, any idea? Have I configured TXT record correctly or anything which needs to change?

Comment: Are you requesting a wildcard certificate? can you open qa.abcd.in exist without SSL? qa.abcd.in must be a valid virtual sub server.

Answer (score 1):

That's because when you ran letsencrypt in virtualmin on the right side you had a bunch of other subdomains on the list. Such as webmail.mydomain.com, admin.mydomain.com, mail.maydomain.com and ofcourse mydomain.com and [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) **(By default mail, webmail, admin subdomains are added. But they are not pointing to your virtualmin server from your Domain Provider )**

**So the issue is that you probably only added an A record at your domain to point to your virtualmin server along with your cname to point www to mydomain.com.**

This means you should only be able to create a certificate for [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com) and mydomain.com. You got me? When you click on Let's Encrypt just select the second radio check and manually add them without subdomains.

If you want to add subdomains you should go back to your domain name provider and point the subdomains to your virtualmin. Or alternatively you can just change the DNS Name Servers from your domain provider to point to the ns1 records of your virtual server provider. But if you change the name servers, now you must create the DNS records like MX, SOA, A, etc with the hosting provider who sells you the virtual server.